# Sorting the two tables with respect one colum ID, heading

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
    Table1 name : **class_subjects**
     +----+---------+-------+
    | ID | class_ID| Paper |
    +----+---------+-------+
    |  1 |       2 | Sub1  |
    |  2 |       7 | Sub3  |
    |  3 |       2 | Sub5  |
    |  4 |       2 | Sub2  |
    |  5 |       4 | Sub1  |
    |  6 |       7 | Sub5  |
    |  7 |       5 | Sub3  |
    |  8 |       5 | Sub2  |
    |  9 |       3 | Sub1  |
    | 10 |       2 | Sub1  |
    | 11 |       1 | Sub9  |
    +----+---------+-------+
     Table2 name : **classes**
    +----+--------------+
    | ID |  className   |
    +----+--------------+
    |  1 | Multimedia   |
    |  2 | Animation    |
    |  3 | Visual EFX   |
    |  4 | Visual Comm  |
    |  5 | Visual Arts  |
    |  6 | BCA          |
    |  7 | BSc          |
    |  8 | BA           |
    |  9 | BCom         |
    | 10 | BFT          |
    +----+--------------+
    I do have two tables with the names 'sjcc_class_subjects' and 'sjcc_classes'.
```

In the first table column '**ClassID**' represents the second table '**ID**'.
         O/p like

```
+-----------+---------+
    | **Animation** |     |
    +-----------+---------+
    | #         | Subject |
    | 1         | Sub1    |
    | 2         | Sub5    |
    | 3         | Sub2    |
    | 4         | Sub1    |
    +-----------+---------+
    +-----+---------+
    | **BSc** |     |
    +-----+---------+
    | #   | Subject |
    | 1   | Sub3    |
    | 2   | Sub5    |
    +-----+---------+
    +-------------+---------+
    | Visual Comm |         |
    +-------------+---------+
    | #           | Subject |
    | 1           | Sub1    |
    +-------------+---------+
```

I am using the following code, but output is not displayed properly. Kindly help me to solve this. Thanks in advance. (Sorry for the poor coding).

```
   <?php
    $sjcc="SELECT classes.ID, classes.className, class_subjects.class_ID, class_subjects.paper FROM classes, class_subjects group by class_subjects.class_ID";      
    $sjcc_result    = $conn->query($sjcc);
    while($sjcc_result_fetch    = $sjcc_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
        <li>                
         <h1>BA MM <?php echo $sjcc_result_fetch['className'];?></h1>
          <table class="table">
          <thead>
          <tr>
           <th>#</th>
           <th>Subject</th>
         </tr>
         </thead>
        <?php
        while($sjcc_result_fetch2    = $sjcc_subject_result->fetch_assoc()) 
       {
        ?>
        <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>1</td>
           <td><?php echo $sjcc_result_fetch2    ['paper_name']; ?></td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
        <?php } ?>
        </table>
     </li>
        <?php } ?>
```

Please help me to solve this issue, I am not finding any solution to go ahead. It would be greatful for me if some

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add ***ORDER BY*** in SQL query.

The ORDER BY statement in SQL is used to sort the fetched data in either ascending or descending according to one or more columns.

By default ORDER BY sorts the data in ascending order.
We can use the keyword DESC to sort the data in descending order and the keyword ASC to sort in ascending order.

Query -

```
SELECT CLASSES.id,
       CLASSES.classname,
       CLASS_SUBJECTS.class_id,
       CLASS_SUBJECTS.paper
FROM   CLASSES,
       CLASS_SUBJECTS
GROUP  BY CLASS_SUBJECTS.class_id 
ORDER BY CLASS_SUBJECTS.class_id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

for order you should use ORDER BY not group  by

```
    SELECT classes.ID
    , classes.className
    , class_subjects.class_ID
    , class_subjects.paper 
    FROM classes
    , class_subjects 
    ORDER  by class_subjects.class_ID
```

You should use explicit  join  and in your case  use  CROSS JOIN 
and if you want distinct result use DISTINCT clause  and not group by

```
    SELECT distinct  classes.ID
    , classes.className
    , class_subjects.class_ID
    , class_subjects.paper 
    FROM classes
    CROSS JOIN  class_subjects 
    ORDER  by class_subjects.class_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

use join to get data from two tables and order by to sort

```
select nt.id,nt.Paper as Subject,ud.className  from class_subjects as nt join classes as ud on nt.class_ID =ud.ID order by ud.className    asc
```